# Angular JS reinitialize service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have an angular js service which returns a node js WebSocket connection.

```
.service('WebSocketService', function(){
    console.log("Starting Web Socket Service...");

    var ws= new WebSocket('wss://127.0.0.1:8443/live');
    return ws;
})
```

I'm using this service in a controller. I want to reconnect to the node server in case of the connection fails. To do that, I need to reinitialize this service from controller ( I understand that services are singleton, so I'm looking for a solution to my problem)

How can do i do that?

Comment: Services are Singleton

Comment: you can create a new method on this service like `this.reinit = function(){ // connect here }` and call this method from controller `webSocketService.reinit()`

Comment: @YordanNikolov  how can i call this method in controller? Currently, i'm returning the connection. What should i return in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using reconnecting-websocket js library for this and it works well!

Reference: https://github.com/pladaria/reconnecting-websocket

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 0):

```
.service('WebSocketService', function(){
    var conn;

    this.connect = function() {
      return new WebSocket('wss://127.0.0.1:8443/live');
    };
    // if you want to connect in the service directly
    conn = this.connect();
})
```

Controller

```
webSocketService.connect()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your socket into another object that your service will return :

```
.service('WebSocketService', function(){
    console.log("Starting Web Socket Service...");

    var ws= new WebSocket('wss://127.0.0.1:8443/live');

    return {ws : ws,
            restart: restart
          };

    function restart() {
        ws = new WebSocket('wss://127.0.0.1:8443/live');
        return ws;
    }

})
```

So, in your controller, I think you need to do the following :

```
.controller('SomeController', ['WebSocketService', '$timeout', function(WebSocketService, $timeout){
    this.ws = WebSocketService.ws;

    this.ws.onclose = function(){
        $timeout(function(){
            this.ws = WebSocketService.restart();
        }, 4000)
    }
}])
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain how i can use this in the controller? i.e how do i restart when connect is lost. Currently, im using this and it doesnt seem to work: WebSocketService.ws.onclose = function(e) {
        console.log('Socket is closed. Reconnect will be attempted in 1 second.', e.reason);
        setTimeout(function() {
         WebSocketService.restart;
        }, 4000);
      };

Comment: done, you basically forgot to execute the restart function

Comment: WebSocketService.ws.onclose = function(e) { console.log('Socket is closed. Reconnect will be attempted in 1 second.', e.reason); setTimeout(function() { WebSocketService.restart(); }, 4000); };

Comment: Please let me know if you find something wrong in above statement. It doesn't seem to work. The method is being executed but connected to not re-opened . Any idea?